# List of book (references) microdata

Tags: html, microdata

I have a list of books that goes like this

```
Title, Author(s), Publisher
Title, Author(s), Publisher
Title, Author(s), Publisher
Title, Author(s), Publisher
...
```

After reading about `HTML5` and `microdata` I think, correct me if I am wrong, that could benefit from some html5 microdata, but I am not sure how one would style this list of books.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you check out the [documentation at schema.org](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html) and in particular the book vocabulary at http://schema.org/Book

Answer (score 2):

A good starting point is the documentation from Google: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170&topic=1088472&ctx=topic
They describe there all three possibilities (microdata, microformats, RDFa) for adding Meta-Information to HTML. Beside that they have testing tool where you can check if your code is correct: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

For you booklist the best fit would imho be the type 'product'